# Chrome Firefox HTML Display

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome

All,

I have couple of queries with respect to displaying html:

I have a background image that is set for the `<body></body>` component of my HTML page using the CSS as follows:

```
body {  
    background: url('XYZ.jpg') no-repeat;  
    background-position: center top;  
    background-size: 100%;  
    background-color: #422102;  
    font-family: "Algerian";  
    font-size: 15pt;  
    color: #F8F8FF;  
}
```

For the setting above, the background image completely covers the display window in Chrome but not in Firefox. I can see the background color in Firefox.

How can I make this consistent?

The contents in both Chrome and Firefox is displayed in CAPITAL letters when I have not even set capital letters for the `<body></body>` section. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `background-size` is not a widely supported CSS property. Use `-moz-background-size` in addition to `background-size` to get it working in FF 3.6+. See [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/background.html).
2. You must have a `text-transform: uppercase` somewhere in your CSS, or your text is literally written in all caps, or you're using a font that only has capital letters.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, But how can I ensure that the background image is 100% for Firefox versions 3.5 or lower since the chart says that `-moz-background-size` is not supported for Firefox 3.5 or below

Comment: You can't achieve this with background images and CSS. I think the only way would be with a dynamically sized image tag via javascript, which comes with a whole host of other problems (js can be disabled, weird z-index issues, image distortion, window scrolling, etc.).